# React useEffect hook is not working with rails

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am using the react hooks but in that useEffect is not working. As in the console start and end are not printing. Also I am using react in rails project.

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const DetailInterview = () => {
  const [participants, setparticipants] = useState([])
  const [interviews, setinterviews] = useState([])


  async function fetchParticipantsList() {
    fetch('/api/v1/participants').
      then((response) => response.json()).
      then((participants) => setparticipants({ participants }));
  };

  async function fetchInterviewsList() {
    const { match: { params: { id } } } = this.props;
    fetch(`/api/v1/interviews/${id}`).
      then((response) => response.json()).
      then((interviews) => setinterviews({ interviews }));

    console.log("sa",interviews)
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('start')
    fetchParticipantsList();
    fetchInterviewsList();
    console.log('end')
  });

  const interviewslist = JSON.stringify(interviews)

  console.log('interviewlist: ',interviewslist)

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>All participants</h3>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Is Published</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {
            interviewslist.map((interview) => {
              return (
                <tr key={interview.id}>
                  <td>{interview.id}</td>
                  <td>{interview.interview_id}</td>
                  <td>
                    {/* <Link to={`/posts/${post.id}`}> */}
                    {interview.participant_id}
                    {/* </Link> */}
                  </td>
                  <td>{interview.created_at}</td>
                  <td>'Yes No'</td>
                </tr>
              )
            })
          }
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default DetailInterview;
```

Can anybody please help me why this is not working. Because of which I think it is showing 
this error:

Uncaught TypeError: interviewslist.map is not a function.

Also this console is printing twice: console.log('interviewlist: ',interviewslist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use interviews not interviewList. You actually stringify interviews to interviewList. So interviewList is basically a string not an array. So Please use interviews.map

```
{
      interviews? interviews.map((interview) => {
          return (
            <tr key={interview.id}>
              <td>{interview.id}</td>
              <td>{interview.interview_id}</td>
              <td>
                {/* <Link to={`/posts/${post.id}`}> */}
                {interview.participant_id}
                {/* </Link> */}
              </td>
              <td>{interview.created_at}</td>
              <td>'Yes No'</td>
            </tr>
          )
        }) : null
}
```

Comment: can you log interviewslist?

Comment: From which line should I log.

Comment: hi I put console.log in my answer. please try code and see what the output in console for interviewList

Comment: We cannot put the console there. It gives an error.

Comment: it should not be. usually we can write code inside of curly braces { /*. we can use console.log here */ }

Comment: But it is giving error, also vscode shows the red underline..

Comment: I updated the code. can u please try again to write console.log as per answer

Comment: An empty array: `interviewlist:  []`

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

Comment: Finally, I got the root cause, I have updated the answer. please check it

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: interviews.map is not a function

Comment: The data is now fetching.

Comment: can you please make it answer by clicking on tick sign if it helps you

Comment: Can you help me in the last error: `Uncaught TypeError: interviews.map is not a function `

Answer (score 1):

You are trying map a string, [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) converts a JavaScript object or value to a JSON string.

Try use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) in this case.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input.      This error is coming after using that.

Comment: Whats the return from '/api/v1/interviews/${id}' is a JSON string?

Comment: It returns a json object.

Comment: Why are trying do this 'JSON.stringify(interviews)' and after trying to map a string? You can work directly with "interviews.map.."

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

Comment: in function components use only "props" instead of "this.props", and pass props to the component like this `const DetailInterview = (props) => { ... }`

Comment: Thanks, I think last error: `Uncaught TypeError: interviews.map is not a function`

Comment: The data is now fetching.